# Enter Parameter Value when getting the last dat of the month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to get the last day of the month by using the following formula I found here at Stackoverflow:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(@test) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(@test), -1)
```

I'm sure this formula should work but when I use it I get a pop-up where I'm asked to enter a parameter value for Month.

Does anyone know how I could solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say you get a popup, where are you running this code?  This works in SQL Server - are you running it in Access?

Comment: Where do you run this query ? In SQL Server Management Studio or elsewhere ?
How did you declare and set the @test variable ?

Comment: I run this code in Access, but i'ts already solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server.  If so, just use [`EOMONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select EOMONTH(@test)
```

I realize that you might be using MS Access.  If that is the case you can use date functions to get the value:

```
select DateAdd(d, -1,
               DateAdd(m, 1,
                       DateSerial(Year(@test), Month(@test), 1))
                      )
              )
```

Comment: I work in Access indeed, this worked perfectly, thank you!